# GPU causing black screen

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, black-screen-of-death

I bought a used Radeon RX 470 GPU from China. Sometimes it works great but usually, at seemingly random moments, the screen will go black, the computer continues running. I have windows 10 pro installed.

I've tried using different cables, monitors etc... I've narrowed it down to the GPU. This does not occur with another GPU in the same computer.

I installed the proper drivers for this GPU and as far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correctly.

The black screen comes at random. I haven't noticed any patterns. Sometimes it will happen immediately after booting, sometimes it will run for hours before it goes black and it doesn't seem to be doing it when pushed hard or anything. Just random.

Please help

Comment: Does the mouse cursor appear or not? If it doesn't, you need to remove the tag black-screen-of-death.

Answer (score 1):

There's *some* troubleshooting you might try, though I'm not sanguine that it's fixable:

- Gentle percussive maintenenance, i.e. tap various IC's and connectors on the GPU board *gently* with a non-conductive prod, such as a toothbrush handle., while the PC is running and displays correctly. If the display blacks out when you hit a certain area, it may just require resoldering a loose component or cleaning and reseating a connector.
- Try a different OS for a while, e.g. [Ubuntu from a Live USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview); no need to actually install it. If that works for a long time without issue, then it's your OS, drivers or software (or possibly HDD).